# Count number of elements in TEXT[]

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I am pretty new to SQL and I was wondering if there is a way to count the number of elements in a text column, such as this on psql:

database => `SELECT * FROM volume LIMIT 2;`

| id | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"} |
| 1 | {"abc", "def", "ghi"} |

(2 rows)

Here, I would like to count the number of elements in the second variable, in total (over the whole dataset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use `cardinality`:

```
select cardinality(col2)
```

Comment: Yes thank you. However this works for each line, then I used ```sum(cardinality(col2))``` to compute the total number of elements in the whole dataset.